# How do I convert this to JavaScript from PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, time

How can I do this in Javascript/jQuery from PHP? I am trying to populate a select list from a start date up to 6 months in advance.

```
    $startDate =  intval( $c->getStartDate($pid) );
    $endDate =  strtotime('+6 month', $startDate);
    $dateSelectList = '<select name="dateSelect" id="dateSelect">';
    $count = 1;
    //populates the select list with the starting date of the course up to the next six months
    for($date = $startDate; $date <= $endDate ; $date = strtotime('+1 day', $date))
    {
        $dateSelectList .= '<option id="select'.$count.'" value="'.$date.'">'.date('D d F Y', $date).'</option>';
        $count++;
    }

    $dateSelectList .= '</select>';
```

Comment: What have you come up with so far?

Comment: I fail to see where the JavaScript enters the picture...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can do this is to use ajax with jQuery. So first step is to modify your code to:

```
$startDate =  intval( $c->getStartDate($pid) );
$endDate =  strtotime('+6 month', $startDate);
$dateSelectList = '';
$count = 1;
//populates the select list with the starting date of the course up to the next six months
for($date = $startDate; $date <= $endDate ; $date = strtotime('+1 day', $date))
{
    $dateSelectList .= '<option id="select'.$count.'" value="'.$date.'">'.date('D d F Y', $date).'</option>';
    $count++;
}

echo $dataSelectList;
```

then save into a separate file say populate.php

Then on the html page you write the following code. Code assumes you have included jquery to your page and that you have a select element with id = dateSelect

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $.get('populate.php',function(data)
   {
       $('#dateSelect').html(data);
   }
});
</script>
```

The above code calls populate.php on load of the page, which returns all the options and injects it into the select element

Comment: Yeah this is what i've done but I realised the select list isnt the only thing i will be manipulating with jquery and this means i will be passing more than set of data to jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt at a php -> javascript port of your code. The exact number of days in a 6 month period depends on the start and end dates of that period so if you need an exact 6 month range, you will need to do more calculations based on the number of days in each of the months involved. The code below assumes 182 days in the 6 month time-frame.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <script>
        function newOption(value, text) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.text = text;
            opt.value = value;
            return opt;
        }

        function formatDate(date) {
            var da = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'],
                ma = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'], 
                dr = date.getDate(),
                wr = date.getDay(),
                mr = date.getMonth(),
                yr = date.getFullYear(),
                dn = da[wr],
                ds = (dr.toString().length == 1) ? '0' + dr.toString() : dr.toString(),
                mn = ma[mr],
                ys = yr.toString(),
                v = dn + ' ' + ds + ' ' + mn + ' ' + ys;

            return v;
        }

        function PopulateDateSelector(startDate, endDate, selector) {
            while(selector.length > 0) selector.remove(0);

            while(startDate < endDate) {
                selector.add(newOption(startDate.getTime().toString(), formatDate(startDate)));
                startDate.setTime(startDate.getTime() + (24*60*60*1000)); 
            }
        } 


    </script>
    <body>

        <select id="dateSelector"></select>

        <script type="text/javascript">             
            var s = document.getElementById('dateSelector'),
                startDate = new Date(),
                endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + (182*24*60*60*1000)); 
                //182 is estimated number of days in a 6 month period.

            PopulateDateSelector(startDate,endDate,s);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The which you search should to be more or less it:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo Javascript populing select field</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $("document").ready(function(){
            nElement = 6;
            sList = {};
            for (i = 0; i<=nElement; i++) {
                var now = new Date();
                var nextDate = new Date();
                nextDate.setMonth(now.getMonth()+(i*6));
                var value = nextDate.getMonth()+"/"+nextDate.getFullYear();
                sList[value] = value;
            }


            $.each(sList, function(key, value){
                var option = $("<option></option>").attr("value",key).text(value);
                $("#demo-select").append(option);

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="demo-select" id="demo-select" ></select>
</body>
```